# R: Replacing column names in while loop with changing data frame names

Tags: r, parsing, dataframe, eval, paste

I currently have a while loop to read HTML tables and in each loop I would like to change the column names to the first row of the current data frame. Let's say I have a data frame named "`df1`". I could accomplish this with the following code:

```
colnames(df1) = unlist(df1[1,])
```

And that works fine, but I can't specify `df1` in the loop because it could be `df1`, `df2`, and so on depending on what `i` equals.

I wrote the following code:

```
colnames(eval(parse(text=paste0("df",1)))) = unlist(eval(parse(text=paste0("df",1)))[1,])
```

I replaced `i` with `1` for testing purposes, but I get the following error:`target of assignment expands to non-language object`

If I run `colnames(eval(parse(text=paste0("df",1))))` on its own, the data looks the same as `colnames(df1)` and same with `unlist(eval(parse(text=paste0("df",1)))[1,])` looking like `unlist(df1[1,])`.

Any help on this will be much appreciated!

Comment: See gregor's answer to this [related post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames) on working with lists of data.frames. You should follow this advice and read these data.frames into a list. It will make working with them easier.

Comment: Hi @lmo, I put these data frames into a list after the while loop completes. Should I work with the column names outside of the while loop in this case? If it's easier, I'll just do that--I didn't know if there was a quick fix to my issue or not.

Comment: If the renaming process is uniform across data.frames, then putting them all into a list and performing the renaming in an `lapply` or the like would make more sense then the `eval` / `parse` paradigm.

Comment: Ok @lmo, I put my data frames into a list using `df_lst <- lapply(ls(pattern='df'),get)`. Then I get the length using `no_dfs <- length(df_lst)`. But then I keep going back to the `eval`/`parse` with this: `i <- 1
for(i in no_dfs){
colnames(eval(parse(text=paste0("df_lst[[",i,"]]")))) = unlist(eval(parse(text=paste0("df_lst[[",i,"]]")))[1,])
}
`. I must not understand the lapply completely. What do you think?

Comment: I just updated my for loop to this: `i <- 1
for(i in no_dfs){
colnames(df_lst[[i]]) = unlist(df_lst[[i]][1,])
}` It runs, but that does not change the colnames for some reason.

Comment: Your `for` loop is only acting on item 1. Use `for(i in seq_along(df_lst))` instead. Also, I'd recommend building lists from data.frames using `df_lst <- mget(ls(pattern='df'))` as it returned a named list, where the names are the name of each data.frame. This can be nice for pulling list elements by their original name.

Comment: Thanks for your help with this @lmo!! I'm still learning a lot about R, and you've been very insightful. I'll start to use your method of building lists from data.frames. I would close this question but I don't have the ability to do so yet.